# how to add blank space before colon in figure caption

Tags: spacing

my thesis template is using caption package for figure captions and when i added figure like this

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=140mm,keepaspectratio=true]{./fig/CH2/figure1.png}
\vspace{4pt}
\caption{Conceptual framework}
%\label{fig : ch2-1}
\end{figure}
```

it gives, Figure 2.1: Conceptual framework
but i have to put additional blank space between colon and figure number due to university format.
like this, Figure 2.1 : Conceptual framework

how can i do this. please help. thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: A space before the colon is used only in French typography.

Answer (score 5):

To achieve what you want, add the following line in your preamble

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{colon}{ : }
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove [demo] option in your document
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{colon}{ : }

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=140mm,keepaspectratio=true]{./fig/CH2/figure1.png}
\vspace{4pt}
\caption{Conceptual framework}
%\label{fig : ch2-1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Note that this also changes the behavior for all captions that use a colon as a separator (e.g. tables).

If you want this behavior **only** for the `figure` environment, replace the above line with the following:

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{mycolon}{ : }
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=mycolon}
```